# Android Physical Device not Recognized by Visual Studio 2013

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, adb

I have started Samsung Kies and attached my android tablet. Samsung Kies recognizes my device that is GT-P3110. The problem is that apparently VisualStudio 2013 doesn't. In fact when I launch the adb command prompt from Visual Studio and type "adb devices" my device is not listed.

How comes?

On the other hand it recognizes my small android cellphone...

Comment: just refresh your adb.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you enable "USB Debugging" in your phones "Developer Settings"

Answer (score 0):

I think that I've understood. Because Visual Studio must be launched after attaching the device.